# Calculate Standard Deviation in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a test table with the following columns:

```
Transaction_date  date
account_number    Number(10)
transaction_ammount  number (10,5)


account_number  transaction_amount    transaction date
111              10000                 10-OCT-2014
111              20000                 10-OCT-2014
111              50000                 08-OCT-2014
111              30000                 06-OCT-2014
222              60000                 10-OCT-2014
222              50000                 10-OCT-2014
222              30000                 08-OCT-2014
```

I need to calculate a rating based on below formula:

rating=((aggregate transaction_amount for 1 day)-(Avg aggregate value for last 10 calender days))/
           Standared Deviation(STDDEV) for last 10 days.

i have used the STDDEV funcation to calculate it.But its giving me incorrect output.

Required out for account_number 111 is :

rank for 10th OCT=SUM for 10th OCt-Avg for all amount for 111(last  10 day)/STDEV for account 111.

rank for 10th OCT=(10000+20000)-((10000+2000+50000+30000)/10)/STDEV(10000,2000,50000,30000)

Please suggest how can i achive this with the help of sql query.Thanks!

Comment: In exactly what way is the output of stddev() incorrect? Are you aware of your typos? (20000 in the test table, but only 2000 in two different places in your rank for Oct 10.)

Comment: I must agree with @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', if we cannot see the code you are executing and given that your logic is flawed above I have to assume you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t1 as (
select '111' account_number, 10000 transaction_amount, to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') transaction_date from dual
union all select '111', 20000, to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
union all select '111', 50000, to_date('08-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
union all select '111', 30000, to_date('06-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
union all select '222', 60000, to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
union all select '222', 50000, to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
union all select '222', 30000, to_date('08-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
),
t2 as (
select account_number, transaction_amount, transaction_date,
       -- aggregate transaction_amount for 1 day
       sum(transaction_amount) over (partition by account_number order by transaction_date range 0 preceding) aggr_amount,

       -- Avg aggregate value for last 10 calender days
       avg(transaction_amount) over (partition by account_number order by transaction_date range 10 preceding) aggr_avg,

       -- Standared Deviation(STDDEV) for last 10 days
       stddev(transaction_amount) over (partition by account_number order by transaction_date range 10 preceding) aggr_stddev
from t1)      
select account_number, transaction_amount, transaction_date,
       aggr_amount - aggr_avg / nullif(aggr_stddev, 0)
from t2;
```